# Support multiple human languages in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I would like to write all the markdown cells I have in both Spanish and English, and have only the Spanish ones show up if that is selected as the running systems main language, or perhaps a language toggle at the top? Is there a jupyter extension that would enable this? Or some work around? I haven't yet been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the closest internationalization work is [i8n impelemenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) in the latest release of the notebook ([5.1.0](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#release-5-1-0)).

See the following [pull request](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/2140/)  and [README](https://github.com/JCEmmons/notebook/blob/jep16/notebook/i18n/README.md) for details:

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own extension that works on cell tags. You could tag the English cells with #english and Spanish with #spanish using the tag toolbar (under `View > Cell Toolbar > Tags`)

Here's a working example of some code that adds a dropdown menu for the different languages you want (in this case I just coded English and Spanish, but it is extendable) and registers the actions to the Jupyter command palette. This hides all cells that have tags that don't have your specific language tag on - so you may want to refine this to suit your needs. Or leave it as is if it's okay :)

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace'
], function(
    Jupyter
) {
    console.log("Language switcher working!");
    var show_selected_language = function(language) {
        language = String.toLowerCase(language);
        console.log("switching languages...");
        // Find all cells with specific language
        var cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();

        cells.forEach(function(cell) {
            if(cell.hasOwnProperty("metadata") && cell.metadata.hasOwnProperty("tags") && cell.metadata.tags.indexOf(language) !== -1) {
                cell.element.show('slow');
            } else if (cell.hasOwnProperty("metadata") && cell.metadata.hasOwnProperty("tags") && cell.metadata.tags.indexOf(language) === -1) {
                cell.element.hide('slow');
            }
        });
    };

    var load_ipython_extension = function() {        
        var lang_dropdown =  $("<div/>").addClass("dropdown btn-group").attr("id","lang-menu");
        var lang_button  = $("<button/>")
                      .addClass("btn btn-default dropdown-toggle")
                      .attr("type","button")
                      .attr("data-toggle","dropdown")
                      .attr("title", "Switch Language")
                      .text("Lang");
        var lang_caret = $("<span>").addClass("caret");
        lang_button.append(lang_caret);

        var lang_dropdown_ul = $("<ul/>")
            .attr("id","lang_menu")
            .addClass("dropdown-menu");

        lang_dropdown.append(lang_button).append(lang_dropdown_ul);

        $(Jupyter.toolbar.selector).append(lang_dropdown);

        function add_new_item(menu, display_text, id) {
            menu.append($("<li/>").attr("id",id)
                                              .append($("<a/>")
                                                      .attr("href","#")
                                                      .text(display_text))
                                                      .click(function() { show_selected_language(display_text);}));
        }
        add_new_item(lang_dropdown_ul, "English", "switch-lang-english");
        add_new_item(lang_dropdown_ul, "Spanish", "switch-lang-spanish");


        var english_action = {
            help: "Switch language to English",
            help_index: "a",
            icon: "fa-language",
            handler : function() { show_selected_language("english");},
        };

        var english_prefix = "language_switcher";
        var english_action_name = "switch-lang-english";

        Jupyter.actions.register(english_action, english_action_name, english_prefix);

        var spanish_action = {
            help: "Switch language to Spanish",
            help_index: "a",
            icon: "fa-language",
            handler : function() { show_selected_language("spanish");},
        };

        var spanish_prefix = "language_switcher";
        var spanish_action_name = "switch-lang-spanish";


        Jupyter.actions.register(spanish_action, spanish_action_name, spanish_prefix);
    };

    return {
        load_ipython_extension : load_ipython_extension
    };
});
```

Save it as a javascript file and then install and enable it like any frontend extension.